# Log4j : DailyRollingFileAppender sometimes doesnt create a new file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, jboss, log4j

I am using log4j for logging. I have hosted my java application(war file) on JBOSS. What I observe is log4j is not creating a new file on daily basis. Instead it is appending logs in a single file. Thing is its not appending on daily basis. Sometimes it creates file whereas sometimes it appends.This is already in prod so I cannot change log4j.Below is my log4j code

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG,R,CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] %m%n
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS} [%p]  [%C] %m%n
log4j.appender.R.File=C://log/pd.log
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.Threshold = DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=WARN
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=WARN
```

My file gets generated but it is not on a regular basis. 
[image]

I have not yet found any thread which can help me in this.

Comment: @miroh :  In my case the file is getting generated but its not on regular basis. If I restart the server then it creates daily say for 10-15 days then it starts appending.Problem is some times the file size increases a lot due to appending